# bootstrap.js auto activate navbar li in header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I added bootstrap in my project for responsive design. All is well but it will make active ABOUT US in header menu but at the time of page is loading, HOME remains active. But as pages loaded completely, ABOUT US become active.

I have taken bootstrap from CDN ([link](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js)).

Below is bootstrap code from line 801 to 830.

```
b.prototype.process = function() {
    var a, b = this.$scrollElement.scrollTop() + this.options.offset,
        c = this.getScrollHeight(),
        d = this.options.offset + c - this.$scrollElement.height(),
        e = this.offsets,
        f = this.targets,
        g = this.activeTarget;
    if (this.scrollHeight != c && this.refresh(), b >= d) return g != (a = f[f.length - 1]) && this.activate(a);
    if (g && b < e[0]) return this.activeTarget = null, this.clear();
    for (a = e.length; a--;) g != f[a] && b >= e[a] && (void 0 === e[a + 1] || b < e[a + 1]) && this.activate(f[a])
}, b.prototype.activate = function(b) {
    this.activeTarget = b, this.clear();
    var c = this.selector + '[data-target="' + b + '"],' + this.selector + '[href="' + b + '"]',
        d = a(c).parents("li").addClass("active");
    d.parent(".dropdown-menu").length && (d = d.closest("li.dropdown").addClass("active")),
        d.trigger("activate.bs.scrollspy")
}, b.prototype.clear = function() {
    a(this.selector).parentsUntil(this.options.target, ".active").removeClass("active")
};
var d = a.fn.scrollspy;
a.fn.scrollspy = c, a.fn.scrollspy.Constructor = b, a.fn.scrollspy.noConflict = function() {
    return a.fn.scrollspy = d, this
}, a(window).on("load.bs.scrollspy.data-api", function() {
    a('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function() {
        var b = a(this);
        c.call(b, b.data())
    })
})
```

My HTML code is as below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header"><div class="slicknav_menu"><margo aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" class="slicknav_btn slicknav_collapsed"><span class="slicknav_menutxt"></span><span class="slicknav_icon slicknav_no-text"><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span><span class="slicknav_icon-bar"></span></span></margo><ul class="slicknav_nav slicknav_hidden" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" role="menu">
  <li> <a href="#home" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Home</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#about" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">About Us</a> 
    <!-- <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Press</a>
          </li>
        </ul> --> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Products </a> 
    <!-- <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Customers</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Integrations</a>
          </li>
        </ul> --> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Services</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Support</a> 
    <!--  <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Product Guide</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Developers</a>
          </li>
        </ul> --> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Register</a> </li>
  <li><a href="contact-us.php" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"> Contact Us </a> </li>
</ul></div> 
    <!-- Stat Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </button>
    <!-- End Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles --> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/kornerStone/" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 7px;"> <img alt="" src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive logo" style="margin-top:11px !important;"> </a> </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
    <!-- Stat Search --> 
    
    <!-- End Search --> 
    <!-- Start Navigation List -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class=""> <a href="#" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"> <a href="#about" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">About Us</a> 
        <!--ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Press</a>
              </li>
            </ul--> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#service" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">Services</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">Register</a> </li>
      <li><a href="contact-us.php" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;"> Contact Us </a> </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Navigation List --> 
  </div>
</div>
```

In that you can see about us `li` has a class ACTIVE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class **nav-default** to the nav ul container in order to show the About Us nav as active (https://jsfiddle.net/4jsaq266/1/):

```
...
<div class="navbar-default navbar-collapse collapse"> 
...
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, 
but my question is different.
My question is I already have a navbar having About US active but I want Home tab active on page load.
I hope your r getting my point.

Comment: I am not sure I understand ... So the class active is added automatically? Because if not, you can remove it from "About Us" parrent <li> in case you don't want anything to show active, and add it to "Home" parrent <li> in case you want home to show active.

Comment: Thats y you are not sure with your answer.
actually, I already added a class active to "HOME" tab but through any JS or CSS( I donot know ), it is adding class active to "about us" and activating that. That's why I m struggling with the code.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with the whole thing? Maybe I'll be able to debug it and find a solution if you show me the entire scenario.

Comment: k 
I will do it 
thanks for your interest
as i will create it, I will post it here.